# Ingest data from Google sheets to make a gantt chart on Google script and serve the HTML as web app

Tags: javascript, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm attempting to create a Google Gantt Chart on Google Script, pulling data from a Google Sheets spreadsheet to serve the HTML as web app. I managed to do the trick with other types of charts, but I think there's some problem with the date format, as I keep getting erros like "Invalid data table format: column #3 must be of type 'date'"

I'm not familiar with Javascript, so I'm really lost here. Here is the code on my Code.gs. The file has to be private, it's on my work Gsuite, but is a simple test with data formatted as in the [Google Gantt Charts documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart).

```
function doGet() {

  return HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile("Index")
  .evaluate()
  .setTitle("MKT Simple Cycle")
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);  
}


function getCycle() {

  var ssID   = "1p4jEZtSk4GoVWvR9OrZj2ou1dpUbl6GHYUlJ1bSVY-s",
  sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0],
  data   = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return data

}
```

And here is the code on my Javascript.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getCycle);

function getCycle() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).getCycle();
}

function drawChart(rows) {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows, false);

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    gantt: {
      trackHeight: 30
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('Cycle'));

  chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

Comment: check the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#data-format) -- all columns should have data, except for _Resource ID_, do you have any blanks?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `sheet.getDataRange().getValues();` returns strings, and the Gantt chart needs *Start Date* and *End Date* to be javascript Date objects.

Cycle through the array you have in `data`, converting the strings in cells 3 and 4 (if you have a *Resource ID* column in your sheet, or cells 2 and 3 if you don't) with Date objects.

```
row[2] = new Date(row[2]);
row[3] = new Date(row[3]);
```

That should fix the problem.